# Statistics for Stack Overflow site

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, unanswered-questions, statistics

I am interested to know statistics on, average time a question remains unanswered on stack overflow, average questions per 1000 that are unanswered, average number of answers per question.

Has any one at Stack Overflow calculated statistics regarding this matter.

Comment: You can probably find this data at https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow.

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/sites also shows the number of questions, average number of answers and percentage unanswered, though for more detailed work, you might find the Data Explorer handy.

Comment: @OneKitten Thanks never knew such site existed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Queries for these statistics are available on https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow.

- [Time to answer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/170387/time-to-answer)
- [Average questions per 1000 that are unanswered](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/190596/average-questions-per-1000-that-are-unanswered)
- [Average number of answers per question](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/82904/average-number-of-answers-per-question)

Comment: This is very nice! I wish more sites where this open-minded!