# What is the number of active experts in Stack Overflow tags?

Tags: discussion, statistics

How many users are actively posting (2 or more) upvoted answers each week in the most popular tags at Stack Overflow?

What is the explanation behind the recent (two-three years) trends in the number of active experts?

Are there any tags that have actually growing community of answerers?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253679/statistics-for-stack-overflow-site

Comment: I don't see why this question deserves the bad reception it got.

Comment: I just got here, but doesn't the second question imply the questioner has the answer to their first question? Asking several questions in a single post also probably didn't help matters.

Comment: @Pekka웃: you did look at the original revision, right?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - fixed.

Comment: @Cerbrus yes, I did. I actually saw the question when it was posted, was about to downvote it, then realized it's to *present the findings,* not asking someone else to do the query. It arguably wasn't worded very well, but heck, we get tons of much worse content here every day - why do we have to come down with prejudice on OPs trying to contribute something meaningful to the site like this, instead of helping them improve their contribution?

Comment: So, I'd advice _against_ dumping a short line into a question. Write out your question first, _then_ start working on a answer, not the other way around.

Comment: Interesting Qt but I had to "refrain" from not down-voting it as it feels like "Clickbait" for Answerers in "small" Tags as "(in) the most popular (Tags)" is not included in the Qt/Thread Title...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the results from a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/342649#graph) on specific tags in Stack Overflow.

The results are valid up to August 2. Please note that end-of-year effects are artifacts of shorter weeks and holidays. The overall trend may exhibit different dates for each tag but two features are prominent: decline since early 2014 and brief resurgence in many tags during second quarter of 2015.

Javascript (peaked in early 2014, a brief resurgence in '15-Q2):

[image]

Java (peaked in early 2014):

[image]

C# (stagnant since 2011, declining since early 2014):

[image]

PHP (stagnant 2012-2014, in decline since then):

[image]

Android (in decline since Q2-2014):

[image]

JQuery (same as for PHP):

[image]

Python:

[image]

HTML:

[image]

---

Growing tags are still there: [angularjs](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/342649/number-of-active-experts-per-week-in-a-tag-so?tagName=angularjs#graph), [vba](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/342649/number-of-active-experts-per-week-in-a-tag-so?tagName=vba#graph) and [excel](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/342649/number-of-active-experts-per-week-in-a-tag-so?tagName=excel#graph), for instance.

Excellent early analysis of the 2014 top user exodus is [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252756/are-high-reputation-users-answering-fewer-questions). A more theoretical analysis is available in [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077) (a Markov chain with an absorbing end state). No idea on the resurgence and decline pattern in 2015, though. (EDIT: Although some folks point out **Panda 4.1 Google update** that occurred IIRC in 2014-09).

Two hypotheses I haven't checked for **individual** SO tags:

- expert burnout rates have changed;
- influx of new experts has shifted drastically.

Comment: Did we really need someone to run the query the ___OP___ linked 4 times, and add them as an answer?

Comment: @Cerbrus - I can do it myself.

Comment: Oh wait, you're the OP. What's the point of this question?

Comment: @Cerbrus - to show how various SO tag communities evolve. Definitely not going to add all the tags, just something to get people to experiment with the query.

Comment: So, how does this question seek input or discussion? You're just showing off a query you made, without taking into account what the most used tags are, it seems (In order of popularity): [_JavaScript, Java, C#, php, Android, jQuery, Python, HTML_](http://stackoverflow.com/tags)

Comment: @Cerbrus - okay, will fix. Other answers may provide discussion, this one (comm.wiki) provides fodder for thought.

Comment: @Cerbrus - fixed.

Comment: You fixed the answer, but that doesn't make the question itself any better.

Comment: Your answer doesn't answer this part of your question "What is the explanation behind the recent (two-three years) trends in the number of active experts?"

Comment: @DavidPostill - would welcome your explanations. Nobody's perfect...

Comment: @DeerHunter I've no idea, and if I made a guess it would be "opinion-based" and not worth 2 cents ;)

Comment: @DeerHunter: Nope. When an (educated) _guess_ can be tested by objective data it's called a hypothesis. An opinion is nothing more than an opinion.

Comment: @DeerHunter  Your data is not objective. Invalid assumption number 1 - "posting (2 or more) upvoted answers each week" does **not** define an expert. There are plenty of cr@p questions and answers that get upvoted for no apparent reason. I post two or more upvoted answers pretty much every day on [su] but I don't consider myself an expert ... you need to find a better definition of "expert"

Comment: @DavidPostill - we may agree to disagree here. You are free to try your own definition by [forking](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/342649/number-of-active-experts-per-week-in-a-tag-so) and editing the query. The point is that these users regularly post answers which are positively regarded by the community.

Comment: @DavidPostill - I edited the query, parameterizing the "minimum number of +scoring answers per week". The trends are the same - https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/342649

Comment: I don't know, that abrupt fall-off exactly one year from the end of the data dump for every single tag smacks of something artificial, rather than a concerted mass-exodus of users. For example, is this somehow impacted by [the system's auto-deletion of abandoned questions after 365 days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006)? We've seen that skew results before.

Comment: @BradLarson - the query takes only upvoted questions into account and as such, shouldn't be susceptible to Community cleanup. If anything, cleanup will bias the results **for** experienced users, not against them (since they may be assumed more likely to refrain from answering cr@p Qs).

Comment: @BradLarson - there's also increase in some communities - excel, vba, angular,js. Haven't run more tests for all the tags, though.

Comment: @BradLarson - would be great if SE team could re-run the queries with historical database versions, though.

Comment: @BradLarson - I've re-run the queries for the original trio (SO/SF/SU) and the results are pretty much the same 6 months later. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261601/shutting-down-recurring-community-self-evaluations/261608#261608

Comment: I often have lapses in reasoning skills, but doesn't this just show business as usual? As time passes and new technologies arise, interests shift and migrate. Was there something specific that these graphs were supposed to point out that I'm completely missing?

Comment: @Gimby - please check against the [cited post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261601/shutting-down-recurring-community-self-evaluations/261608#261608) on MSE. Inter-tag ebb and flow are fine, but the secular trend is to lower the number of people posting answers on SO _in general_.