# Number of active members for each tag

Tags: discussion, statistics

I want to to find the number of active members of each tag in Stack Overflow. Active members are those who answer questions in each week or have a good score. In a nutshell everyone except new users with fewer than 10 reputation points. I read [What is the number of active experts in Stack Overflow tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300672/what-is-the-number-of-active-experts-in-stack-overflow-tags) and find [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/342649#graph) on specific tags in Stack Overflow. But it gives active members in weeks in the year.

To my desired for comparison I change that query and run the following query:

```
-- Time series of the number of active experts per week
-- Where "active expert" is someone who has posted more than one upvoted answer.
-- Per Deer Hunter's definition in http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261608/
--


  select
      t.tagname, count (*) as NumAnswers
  from users u, posts p, posts q, posttags pt, tags t
  where
        p.owneruserid = u.id
    and p.posttypeid = 2
    and p.score > 0
    and p.ParentId = q.id 
    and q.posttypeid = 1
    and pt.postid=q.id
    and t.id = pt.tagid 
    and (t.tagname='c' OR t.tagname='java' OR t.tagname='mysql' OR t.tagname='c#')
  group by t.tagname
```

Now I want to find out whether that is the right query for my desired output.

Comment: @majidhajibaba by best guess is that some think that working query improvement and review requests should be posted on Code Review, for example: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/50920/sede-query-for-rep-trivia, not on meta, as it does not concern site policies or how it works. P.s. In its current state, the query simply counts users who posted anything positively received any time, not exactly what I would call "active"...

Comment: Oh! Sorry because I'm not familiar with stackoverflow groups. I'm really appreciate for your nice suggestion and your review on my code.

Comment: @majidhajibaba - well, that's just a guess, but I would post there (or on main SO if you have a problem with implementing it) - plus, you are more likely to get more feedback there :) P.s. I would also argue (that also concerns the original query) that "weekly" is too short-term for SO, even I can go for a week or two without posting, and I consider myself moderately active. Also, to fine-grain further, one should probably consider users who mostly post comments and/or moderate content

Comment: Thank you @Oleg. No need because the below response if OK for me and has no limitation with week. So active members like you will be included in the result.

Comment: @majidhajibaba - apologies for the confusion, the last note was not about your query and rene's update, but about the original definition of an "active member" (of course the issue is not present in your query as it counts total users)

Comment: Yes! it is a good idea. Please inform me if you post such question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I expect [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1285151) to cut it:

```sql
 select
      t.tagname, count (distinct p.owneruserid) as Users
  from users u, posts p, posttags pt, tags t
  where
        p.owneruserid = u.id
    and p.posttypeid = 2
    and p.score > 0
    and pt.postid=p.ParentId
    and t.id = pt.tagid 
    and (t.tagname='c' OR t.tagname='java' OR t.tagname='mysql' OR t.tagname='c#')
  group by t.tagname
```

Notice how I changed `count(*)` into `count( distinct p.owneruserid)` to not count number of answer but the unique userids within each tag.

To stay sane use [this version](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1285178) kindly offered by [Larnu](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2029983/larnu)

```sql
SELECT t.tagname,
       COUNT(DISTINCT p.owneruserid) AS Users
FROM users u
     JOIN posts p ON p.owneruserid = u.id
     JOIN posttags pt ON pt.postid = p.ParentId
     JOIN tags t ON t.id = pt.tagid
WHERE p.posttypeid = 2
  AND p.score > 0
  AND t.tagname IN ('c','java','mysql','c#')
GROUP BY t.tagname;
```

it fixes all the other issue the original query had, like proper JOIN syntax and utilizing newer language constructs.

Comment: I do suggest switching off that archaic ANSI-89 join syntax the OP is using here though. :)

Comment: Thank you! the results are more acceptable!!!

Comment: Made a [fork](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1285178) which doesn't use 31 year old JOIN syntax ;)

Comment: @Larnu need add new condition??

Comment: No, @majidhajibaba , i said I made it so it *"doesn't use 31 year old JOIN syntax"* Implicit joins were superseded by explicit joins some 28 years ago.

Comment: OH. I got it. I run it just one time. So write it hastily.

Comment: @Larnu but I'm over 31 year old, what do you expect? I'm way over due ;)

Comment: I'm over 31 too, @rene , but still I'm not using it. If that trend followed, I should be using MS-DOS still too ;)

Comment: MS-DOS is for babies. CP/M for the win!