# How does the number of members in a collective compare to all active Stack Overflow users in the tag set of the collective?

Tags: discussion, statistics, collectives

There are currently two collectives and they are defined among other things by a set of tags (for the Go collective [66 tags](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/go?tab=tags) all related to the Go language) and a set of users (for the Go collective currently [4612](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/go?tab=members) members, initially fast increasing now more slowly) that decided to join the collective.

I wonder, how do the current number of users in a collective compare to all potential users that are active in the tags of the collective and could be members. Is this fraction rather large or rather small? Are basically all users within this tag set collectivized or almost none? Are there differences between (the two) collectives with regard to this measure? To state the motivation more vividly: Have collectives taken over certain tags or are they a relatively marginal group?

Also, do higher or lower fractions correlate with reputation, i.e. are proportionally more high rep users part of a collective or rather low rep users more often in a collective?

I drew a picture of what I ideally would like to have:

[image]

But as a minimal goal I would also just settle for total numbers of active tag-set-users for all current collectives to get a better idea of the impact of collective organization.

To answer this question one would need to define active tag-set-users. I propose to define it as all users of Stack Overflow that have asked or answered at least once in any of the tags in the tag set and have been seen at least once since June 23rd. This is surely not perfect, but I cannot think of anything better. Would there be a better measure of potentially interested users available?

A couple of things make this question difficult to answer. The members of a collective are [not currently stored in the data explorer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408734/town-hall-collectives-on-stack-overflow/408779#comment852659_408779) and only available on the web, getting a reputation histogram for them would be tedious. Also the set of tags of a collective is difficult to obtain automatically. How to best filter for them in the data explorer?

Maybe the company has some numbers on that and maybe (although I doubt that) it even wants to share them.

To make sure that this question hasn't been asked before I looked at all ~40 questions in the meta collectives tag and didn't find anything related there, but I also found [What is the number of active experts in Stack Overflow tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300672/what-is-the-number-of-active-experts-in-stack-overflow-tags) and [Number of active members for each tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400650/number-of-active-members-for-each-tag).

Comment: "and have been seen at least once in the last 6 months" - collectives have only been live for roughly 3 weeks, thus it doesn't seem useful to include people in your count who were last seen half a year ago. A better metric would be users that visited the site after june 23.

Comment: @l4mpi That's right. I thought about that people not being seen for at least 6 months likely don't come back ever, but people having visited after June 23rd are the ones that potentially could have joined the collective, so it's more meaningful. Changed it.

Comment: if anyone wants to visualize this: The OP said this data isn't available, so I've gathered a list of user ids for the go and google cloud collective with 4586 and 3378 members as of "right now" respectively. Go: https://rentry.co/afz4g google cloud: https://rentry.co/2rmnf (ids from /u/xxx urls, separated by `, `). I hope those are somehow helpful

Comment: Is the red poking above the green a quirk of what was used to make the graph, or are there some high-rep users in the collective who have never touched the tag?

Comment: @Izkata The graph is just a sketch, most likely the green curve is always above the red curve, but with the given definitions it wouldn't have to be so. Members in a collective do not need to be active in the collective's tags. One might reduce the members of a collective to those active in the collective's tags but that would further complicate the task. The question would then be: How many active users in a tag set are also members of the corresponding collective?

Comment: @jemand771 I went ahead and dumped all those IDs into a couple SEDE queries for ease of use, in case anyone finds them useful or wants to use them for some analysis: [Go Collective Members](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1435635/members-of-go-collective-manual-table), [GCloud Collective Members](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1435663/members-of-gcloud-collective-manual-table).

Comment: What does this sentence mean please? `Took collectives over certain tags or are they rather a marginal group`

Comment: @QHarr  I wanted to express the notion that maybe almost all questions and/or answers in a set of tags are created by members of a collective (take over) or almost none are (marginal) or something in between.

Comment: To clarify even more: the question is simply about the meaning of the number of members of a collective. Is 4k impressive or not? To give this number meaning, one needs another number to compare against.

Comment: @QHarr Maybe a clearer phrasing would be "Have collectives *taken* over certain tags or are they a relatively marginal group"